# Use an SSD Drive in the CD Rom Tray

Tags: ssd, cd-drive

i just bought a tray to replace my CD Rom Drive and insert an SSD Disc over there.
The second SSD taht is in the tray still has Ubuntu installed inside.
The main Ubuntu installation is on a Liteon memory Card.
The tray fitted well but when i boot the laptop chooses the Disc-on-the-tray instead if the Liteon, thus i can't move forward and format the Disc-on-the-tray.
How should i make use of the second SSD-Disc-on-the-tray through my current installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: change your boot order. put internal HDD above internal CD

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that even though i set this priority in the bios it still boots from the CDrom tray and overrirdes tha built in memory card

Comment: BIOS may be starting from the drive that it sees as CD-ROM.  Try moving the CD drive lower in the boot order, or disabling CD boot.

Comment: check system specifications in system settings/bios ...  can it see the built in SSD?

Comment: @ravery yes it sees the ssl in the cd rom tray. Zeiss Ikon I did disable the cd rom from boot option but still in the end it did boot from the cd rom tray

Comment: I also deactivated the boot legacy option that prioritised the cd rom and now it gives me the error Boot device not found , pleas install an operating system on your hard disc, hard disc (3f0), for more information please visit hp.com/go/techcenter/startup

Comment: I managed to format the second SSD using a ubuntu live cd. Still the laptop insists on booting from the SSD and gives me error that there is no operating system detected. I need to say that the laptop Ubuntu OS is installed in a liteon SSD memory card installed in the machine.